# Kotlin function with unspecified return type

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin how do you declare a function with an unspecified return type? For example, if I have a function that is to return a list of integers, but in the case of null input it should return just `null`, instead of a List.
How do I declare a function that could either return a MutableList or a null?

Comment: Bare in mind that using `null` should be avoided, especially in case like this where you can just return empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to declare your type as nullable by using the `?` at the end of the type declaration.

For example, this function takes a non-null `Boolean` and returns either a `MutableList` of `Int` or a `null`:

```
fun maybeGetList(input: Boolean): MutableList<Int>? =
    if (input) mutableListOf(1) else null
```

Kotlin has [quite extensive documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Todd gave an good answer based on what you asked for, but if you are using Kotlin then it might be better to learn to use it properly.

Using `null` should be avoided as much as possible, that is why Kotlin even has null-safe types so it forces you to rethink your code and try to write it without nasty `?`, just look at that sign, it is like it asks you do you really want to do this.

Now in your case you even have 2 great options for avoiding `null` and writing more idiomatic Kotlin:

1. Return empty list:

   ```
   fun getList(condition: Boolean): List<Int> 
       = if(condition) listOf(1,2,3) else emptyList()

   fun getMutableList(condition: Boolean): MutableList<Int>
       = if(condition) mutableListOf(1,2,3) else mutableListOf()
   ```
2. Use `Optional` from Java:

   ```
   fun getOptionalList(condition: Boolean): Optional<List<Int>>
           = if (condition) Optional.of(listOf(1, 2, 3)) else Optional.empty()
   ```

You might think that doing this adds complexity but its quite the opposite, using `null` adds much more complexity because when you return it you must handle that `null` on every place you call this method, this way you encapsulate dangerous state instead of spreading it.

Comment: Seems like [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). Great answer!